# run a .js remotely ssh

Tags: javascript, batch-file, ssh

I am connected from putty to cygwin through ssh (from a computer to another), and I am trying to execute a .js which is on the remote computer (the command I use is cscript Jav.js). If I execute manually from localhost the .js works (execute a .bat and echo the path), and if i try thought ssh from putty it doesn't work (only echos). The .js script is:

```
var WshShell =WSH.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");

function runApp(which) {
 WScript.Echo(which);
 WshShell.Run (which,8,true);
}

runApp("Ascript.bat");
```

Please tell me how can i make the script work (execute the .bat) remotely

Comment: and why so complicated? You can use `wmic` , `schtasks` or `psexec` for remote execution.

Comment: For some reasons I can't use wmic, schtasks or psexec. It is another way to run the script ? please note that i do not have administration rights.